# How do I clean a blob before copying to it (Azure release pipeline)

Tags: azure-devops

My release pipeline uploads to blob storage using 
[Azure File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops)

I want to delete the existing files in the blob before copying over the new files.

The help shows that

```
cleanTargetBeforeCopy: false
```

only applies to a VM

(since it is a release pipeline I can't edit the YAML anyway)

The tool tip for Optional Arguments shows

> Optional AzCopy.exe arguments that will be applied when uploading to
>   blob like, /NC:10. If no optional arguments are specified here, the
>   following optional arguments will be added by default. /Y,
>   /SetContentType, /Z, /V, /S (only if container name is not $root),
>   /BlobType:page (only if specified storage account is a premium
>   account). If source path is a file, /Pattern will always be added
>   irrespective of whether or not you have specified optional arguments.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to delete the existing files in the blob before copying over the new files.

If you want to override the blobs during run copy file task, we neeed to add another optional argument at all.

As you mentioned that if we don't add optional Arguments. **/Y** paramter is added by default.

The blobs will be replaced by the new files by default when run Azure Copy Files task.

If you want to clean the container, you could use the Azure Powershell command to [delete the container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/remove-azurestoragecontainer?view=azurermps-6.13.0) and [recreate the new one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontainer?view=azurermps-6.13.0) before run the Azure copy file task.